# Question about define function and list of string

Tags: python-3.x, function, beautifulsoup

1. I have defined a bs4 function called `extract_movie(url)`
2. Now, I have a list of serval links: `movie_links = ['https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111161', 'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0068646', 'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0071562']`
3. If I run `extract_movie(movie_links[0])`, the output is`['The Shawshank Redemption']`

My question is how can I obtain a list of `['The Shawshank Redemption', 'The Godfather', 'The Godfather: Part II']`

I tried the code below, but it does not work

```
movie_name = []
for i in movie_links:
    name = extract_movie(movie_links[0:2:1])
    movie_name.append(name)
```

Comment: You are looping `i` over all of the links in the list, but you aren't doing anything with it: you call `extract_movie()` with exactly the same parameter each time, so it's going to return the same value each time.  You just want `extract_movie(i)`.

Comment: You can do this without a `for` statement using a comprehension. It is as simple as `movie_names = [extract_movie(link) for link in movie_links]`.